# Can't find Postgres Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

I have been setting up my new macbook and trying to run Rails MVCs that I made on my old mac. I installed Postgresql and found I was unable to run apps in my local host because of a missing psql password. I found this strange because I didn't remember using any passwords with psql in the past, nor did I set one this time.

I uninstalled and reinstalled postgres in the hope that I had just forgotten setting a password, but I am finding the same problem. I'm also unable to use the psql because I'm asked for a password, but I haven't set one.

Can't find anything else related online or on the postgres site, so help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: you must have nad trust for socket conections in hba_file previously

Comment: Can you show exactly what happens and at what point ? Is it when you try to run `rails s`?

Comment: usually it's your root password. try to solve it in your psql first, after that proceed to rails the password seeting in rails is in database.yml

Comment: Set all connections in your hba file to trust.

Comment: Micael - this is in the local host, the message I receive is: PG::Connection Bad / fe_sendauth: no password supplied - if I had the password for psql then I could enter this in database.yml, but I have no idea what the password is